# Xamarin.Forms update via NuGet failed

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, nuget, xamarin.forms

Hi every time when creating Xamarin.Forms Shared OR Portable project i open Nuget package manager and navigating to Updates tab. And every new project it gives me that i can update Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin support library v4. WHY? why i can not download it one time and use it anywhere.

Because second problem is that i have problem while updating this packages. please look to Second image

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suspend Resharper and try again.

Comment: i uninstalled Resharper. But question: WHY? It is just ReSharper with license. And i have send feedback to ReSharper. Thanks. Now it works.

Comment: You don't need to uninstall it, just suspend it via Tools->Options looks like a R#/Xamarin incompatibility that has to be fixed. Once update is completed you can turn R# on.

Comment: Install ReSharper 8.2.3 - https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-408376 is fixed there.